# Cómo solucionar este problema de toolchain.prf

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Cuando le doy **run** a mi proyecto me salen estos errores:

> C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:76: Variable QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS is not defined.
>   C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:129: Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.
>   C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:76: Variable QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS is not defined.
>   C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:129: Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.
>   C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:76: Variable QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS is not defined.
>   C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:129: Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.

¿Alguien sabe por qué salen dichos errores?
Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es cuando quiere compilar, puedes probar agregando:

```
QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS="PATH AL DIRECTORIO INCLUDE"
```

Dentro de las opciones de qmake en el proyecto o tu Qt no está bien instalado en Windows.

Yo lo he instalado sin problemas siguiendo los pasos indicados y usando MSYS2.